# Startup delay due to OSGI bundle resolving

Tags: eclipse, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, equinox

I'm currently trying to migrate our product to work on jdk 11 and as a part of this effort upgraded the osgi framework (upgrading from equinox osgi version 3.9.1.v20130814-1242). We managed to upgrade the components and start the pack but currently we see high startup time (startup freezes in the middle for some additional time). we suspect it is due to bundle wiring.

I checked the bundle status using ss comand and all the bundles were in Active state.

Then I enabled osgi debug logs for wiring (org.eclipse.osgi/resolver/wiring) and notice one component trying to wire to same component repeatedly

Following is a part of the log. similar repeated logs for different components can be seen during this startup freeze time . (I attached the full log in http://download2265.mediafire.com/cov16dra60kg/n808avzytuv3xxb/logs.txt)

```
RESOLVER: Wirings for resolved bundles:
Resource
    osgi.identity; osgi.identity="tomcat"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="7.0.85.wso2v1"
Wiring
    [1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=*)"; resolution:="dynamic"; cardinality:="multiple" -> [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="axiom"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.2.11.wso2v12"]
RESOLVER: Wirings for resolved bundles:
Resource
    osgi.identity; osgi.identity="tomcat"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="7.0.85.wso2v1"
Wiring
    [1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=*)"; resolution:="dynamic"; cardinality:="multiple" -> [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="axiom"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.2.11.wso2v12"]
RESOLVER: Wirings for resolved bundles:
Resource
    osgi.identity; osgi.identity="tomcat"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="7.0.85.wso2v1"
Wiring
    [1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=*)"; resolution:="dynamic"; cardinality:="multiple" -> [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="axiom"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.2.11.wso2v12"]
RESOLVER: Wirings for resolved bundles:
Resource
    osgi.identity; osgi.identity="tomcat"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="7.0.85.wso2v1"
Wiring
    [1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=*)"; resolution:="dynamic"; cardinality:="multiple" -> [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="axiom"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.2.11.wso2v12"]
RESOLVER: Wirings for resolved bundles:
Resource
    osgi.identity; osgi.identity="tomcat"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="7.0.85.wso2v1"
Wiring
    [1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=*)"; resolution:="dynamic"; cardinality:="multiple" -> [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="axiom"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.2.11.wso2v12"]
```

Can anyone please help me in identifying the problem and why it tries to wire to same package (any additional methods to narrowdown the issue). Same tomcat version was used in the old OSGI version but didn't see this kind of freezing in the middle.

Thanks a lot